# What do honorifics represent?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhagim

What is the custom for adding a honorific after a deceased person's name? For example we say for [Avraham Avinu - [alav hashalom](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.11). While the ari has zecher tzadik livracha. Does one signify more of a stature? What about zichut yagen aleinu?
My question being how does one decide to use one over the other?

Comment: Abraham Avinu is traditionally called ע"ה for "eved hashem". The Ari was never called that and hence doesn't get that suffix

Comment: אאע"ה = אברהם אבינו עליו השלום. No?

Comment: No. Maybe some modern writers who don't know better intend that, but classically it stood for עבד השם. Alav Hashalom is a Muslim expression Peace Be Upon Him which was more recently incorporated to Judeo-Arabic at some point

Comment: @DoubleAA great information could you share a source of further reading?

Comment: @DoubleAA A lot of mishnayos on Sefaria say "alav hashalom". I'd have to check older manuscripts of the Mishnah to see if they were later additions

Comment: @robev Those are indeed later expansions of rashei tevot or straight additions.

Comment: @rabbikaii see https://hakirah.org/Vol%203%20Broyde.pdf

Comment: @robev My [search of appearances of "עליו השלום
" in the Mishnah on Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), returned only 3 distinct results: 2 for Avot, and 1 for Kiddushin. In [Mechon Mamre's edition of Avot](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm) (based on Maimonides' manuscript), "אברהם אבינו" appears 4 times, without a honorific. In [their Mishnah Kiddushin](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h37.htm) it doesn't appear at all, as 4:13[14] there is shorter.

Comment: "_For example we say for \[Avraham Avinu - [alav hashalom](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.11)._" Regarding the link: The [Mishnah based on the Kaufmann manuscript, edited by Dan Be'eri](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.3.11?lang=he&vside=Mishnah_based_on_the_Kaufmann_manuscript,_edited_by_Dan_Be%27eri|he&with=Translation%20Open&lang2=he), doesn't have "alav hashalom" there, nor does [Mechon Mamre's edition of Avot](https://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm).